# simplify stupid loop for numpy argmin

Tags: python, numpy

How can I simplify the loop I wrote here in numpy style?

```
X     = np.random.random([10,15,20])
Y     = np.random.random([10,15,20,5])
Z     = np.zeros([10,15,5])

min_X = np.argmin(X,axis=2)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(15):
        Z[i,j,:] = Y[i,j,min_X[i,j],:]
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you Divakar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's NumPy builtin - [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) for that (needs few extra steps as it needs the indexing array to have same number of dims) -

```
np.take_along_axis(Y,min_X[...,None,None],axis=2)[...,0,:]
```